# JSF 2 setup issue in Tomcat 7 (java.lang.InstantiationException: com.sun.faces.application.ServletContextSensitiveSingletonStore)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, myfaces, tomcat7

I have an issue that keeps arising with JSF 2 and Tomcat 7.0.0. When I setup Apache MyFaces 2.0.4 (by putting all the jars in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder), Tomcat deploys my WAR file successfully.

However, when I setup JSF (Mojarra 2.1.0 - FCS) the same way as I do MyFaces, the following exception gets through (and this causes Tomcat to fail).

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.sun.faces.application.ServletContextSensitiveSingletonStore
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4771)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:674)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1390)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:998)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:576)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
```

I've done Google Searches but there are no valid solutions to fix this issue.

My web.xml is version 3.0 (although this is unecessary but I put it here in case someone asks).

Any possible reasons why this doesn't work on Tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to [JSF issue 1937](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1937) which was caused by accidently using Glassfish-specific code in the JSF impl, since 2.1.0 beta 9. It should however already be fixed in 2.1.0 FCS. I haven't tried it on Tomcat 7 yet, but it works for me on JBoss 6 (which uses a fork of Tomcat 7 under the covers). Alternatively, you can also use the latest 2.0, which is currently [2.0.4](http://java.net/projects/javaserverfaces/downloads/download/release%252Fmojarra-2.0.4-FCS-binary.zip). It certainly works on Tomcat 6/7.

---

**Update**: I can reproduce this with 2.1.0 FCS on Tomcat 7.0.11:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.application.ServletContextSensitiveSingletonStore
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.sun.faces.application.ServletContextSensitiveSingletonStore
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4618)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I'd kick issue 1937 and complain that it's still not fixed for Tomcat yet. In the meanwhile, you'd have to use Mojarra 2.0 instead.

Comment: yes, I have read the JSF issue already, but it hasn't helped in my case. It seems that the fix was committed (release 8914) but the problem still persists. Let me try the *archived* 2.0.4

Comment: Mojarra 2.0.4 works, but still, it's not yet fixed on 2.1.0. Thanks for the update, I guess it's one step forward, 2 steps back.... :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Wouldn't you consider Glassfish? See also [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html).

Comment: I have read your tutorial & it's been of great help. After playing with Tomcat, WAS and JBoss for years, I'm still yet to find out why I should jump to Glassfish.

Comment: I think it's time I moved to Glassfish. My rebel in my has surrendered. :-)

Comment: GlassFish 3 was good, but GlassFish 4 is a rampage. Better consider JBoss AS 7, EAP 6 or WildFly 8 instead. My future JSF 2.2 tutorial will definitely be WildFly 8 based.

Comment: I have been using WildFly 8 (after using JBoss 7 and EAP 6 last year), JSF 2.2 and Java 7 this whole year already. It's just that my client is fully on Glassfish so I have to learn the system as well. What do you mean that Glassfish 4 is a rampage?

Comment: I know its old, but moving from jsf 2.1.0 to 2.1.2 solved this issue for me.