# could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, icefaces

Hi i am trying to use following technologies together:

- **JSF 2.1.0**
- **ICEFaces 2.0.2** which is according to their documentation, works fine with **JSF 2.1.x**
- **Tomcat 6**

my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      version="2.5"> 

  <display-name>appName</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>

  </context-param>


  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>



  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

but when trying to run my application, i got the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:815)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:317)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:112)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

any ideas why ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSF 2.1 [requires](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.0/releasenotes.html) a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, yet Tomcat 6 is only a [Servlet 2.5 compatible](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) container. You've 2 options:

1. Downgrade JSF 2.1 to JSF 2.0 (Mojarra 2.0 is [currently](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) at 2.0.6).
2. Upgrade Tomcat 6.0 to Tomcat 7.0 (and change `web.xml` root declaration conform Servlet 3.0).

If you choose option 2 (upgrading to Tomcat 7.0), then you should upgrade Mojarra 2.1.0 to *at least* Mojarra 2.1.1 (it's [currently](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) already at 2.1.3). This is required because Mojarra 2.1.0 contains a bug in the annotation scanner which makes it incompatible with Tomcat and Jetty.

#### See also:

- [Mojarra 2.1.0 - FCS doesn't work with tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805928)

Comment: what's in JSF 2.1 and not in 2.0 , are the improvements and features in 2.1 are a lot and important ? and are the versions 2.0.6 and 2.1.3 are stable ?

Comment: As to new features, check this: http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.0/whatsnew.html As to stability, both are latest stable releases.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem using two approaches :

1.Two different version jsf were removed (eg. jsf 1.x or jsf2.x) or two different jsf implementation were removed (mojarra jsf or myfaces) from project .And I used only one implementation either mojarra (or myfaces) but not both .I had done same in case of jsf different version jars (i.e jsf 2.x jars were used)not jsf 1.x.

2.Remove @ManagedBean annotation from interfaces.

Comment: This answer doesn't match OP's concrete question. You likely meant to answer a different question. You can find such one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897900/java-lang-illegalstateexceptioncould-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-ap