# OmniFaces JAR not allowing my app to start or run in Tomcat 7.0.32

Tags: jsf, tomcat7, omnifaces

I am attempting to migrate from Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to Tomcat 7.0.32, since everyone says that Atmosphere (PrimeFaces Push) works perfectly with Tomcat, while it does not work with Glassfish.

I already added Mojarra 2.1.4 JAR to Tomcat /lib to get pass the error that is discussed in the following:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848341/classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener-for-jsf-project-u)

Now, it seems as though I need to remove OmniFaces (1.3 SNAPSHOT) JAR from my classpath, because it is causing errors. It might be best to read from bottom-to-up, because FullAjaxExceptionHandler showed up as error first, so I commented that out of my app, and then OmniPartialView showed up next, but honestly, I prefer not to remove OmniFaces.

OmniFaces is causing error discussed in the following:

[could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957070/could-not-find-factory-javax-faces-application-applicationfactory)

Below is server log. Please read from bottom-to-up.

```
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('com.sun.faces.ApplicationAssociate', 'com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate@12f3aa66')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('com.sun.faces.InitFacesContext', 'com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext@142d1015')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration', 'com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration@4bdd1969')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.InitFacesContext', 'com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext@1a7add0c')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('com.sun.faces.InitFacesContext', 'com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext@1a7add0c')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.InitFacesContext', 'com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext@53a9dd25')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.patternCache', '{}')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration', 'com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration@34f5d30c')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('com.sun.faces.facesInitializerMappingsAdded', 'true')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.htmlTLVEnabled', 'false')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.webresources', '[]')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager_ANNOTATION_SCAN_TASK', 'java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@69ed807f')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('javax.faces.FactoryFinder.FactoryManagerCacheKey', '1352182177715')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.ApplicationAssociate', 'com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate@6fcbb778')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory', 'com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl@535d7af8')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('javax.faces.BEANS_VALIDATION_AVAILABLE', 'false')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager_ANNOTATION_SCAN_TASK', 'java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@69ed807f')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl', 'org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl@882b46f')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.errorPagePresent', 'false')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeReplaced('com.sun.faces.InitFacesContext', 'com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext@53a9dd25')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1dd3e5cf')
    Nov 06, 2012 1:10:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1453)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:305)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 40 more
    Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:616)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:482)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:138)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:959)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
    ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:614)
    ... 48 more

    Nov 06, 2012 1:20:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1453)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:305)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 40 more
    Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:616)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:482)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:138)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:959)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
    ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContextFactory
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:614)
    ... 48 more
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have resolved this already. I removed Mojarra 2.1.4 JAR from tomcat /lib folder and added to my project (web app) classpath (list of libraries in NetBeans), restarted Tomcat7.0.32, rebuild project/app, deployed app to Tomcat, and this error no longer shows up in server log.

Now I'm dealing with other issues (JPA, my database connection, etc... that was all configured and working in Glassfish).

Comment: Consider using TomEE instead.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I did consider TomEE some weeks/months ago and thought about it last night, but I decided to postpone migration to Tomcat (EE) for now, since I have business requirements to meet. Atmosphere is nice to have, but I'm considering CDI and server sent events instead for pushing data from server to client (who needs a chat application via websockets right now? not me...smile). One thing I learned about Glassfish and Mojarra, they really make JSF development 'easy'. I am about performance 'now', too, so MyFaces Core, CDI, OpenWebBeans are being considered.