# RichFaces 5 on Tomcat 7: could not find factory

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tomcat7

This question is similar to: 
[java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897900/could-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-application-applicationfactory-jav)

But unfortunately it is not my case. I have `richfaces-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar` inside my WAR and `jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final.jar` in the Tomcat lib folder. Nothing else. I don't use MyFaces and never did.

The log is the following:

```
Grave: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
dic 12, 2013 1:41:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Grave: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1008)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:343)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: "jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final.jar" why that one and not the proper JSF jar you can download from javaserverfaces.java.net? I think you have only the API and no JSF implementation here.

Comment: @Gimby you solved my problem! If you transform your comment in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Vitalij: Where exactly did you learn about installing JSF on Tomcat that way? Dropping a copy of JBoss AS server specific JAR file in Tomcat's `/lib` isn't making any utter sense and this way I can contact the resource's author about this severe misinformation.

Comment: @BalusC well I started with the official RichFaces 5.0.0-Alpha1 maven archetype that uses the JBoss specific JAR. I think that the archetype is targeted to JBoss, but I wanted to use Tomcat. Here's the link to the archetype: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.archetypes/richfaces-archetype-simpleapp/5.0.0.Alpha1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final.jar" why that one and not the proper JSF jar you can download from javaserverfaces.java.net? I think you have only the API and no JSF implementation here.

(Don't know how to convert a comment into an answer, so I just reposted).

Comment: Yes I meant repost. Thank you!