# JSF tags don't render in XHTML pages - Spring Boot + JSF 2.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsf

I'm trying to implement a webapp using Spring Boot and JSF 2.2.

I've managed to set up Spring Boot correctly and I can display normal HTML with a controller. But XHTML pages are not rendering correctly.

I believe it is to do with my configuration but I cannot figure out what it is.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.1 on macOS High Sierra.

Here is my pom.xl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jsf-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.latwoa.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

As well as the JSF bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class JsfBean {

    private String welcomeMessage = "Populated by JSF created bean";

    public String getWelcomeMessage() {
        return welcomeMessage;
    }
}
```

And the XHTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
<f:view>

    <h:head></h:head>

    <!--Main Body -->
    <h:body>

        <h1>Welcome to JSF spring boot tutorial</h1>

        <h:outputText value="foo bar" />

        <h3>#{jsfBean.welcomeMessage}</h3>

    </h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

Like I mentioned above, the `<h1>` displays fine. But `<h:outputText value="foo bar" />` and `#{jsfBean.welcomeMessage}` are not rendered.

Comment: Did you  look at the html source on the client? And then look for duplicate questions. I think (99% sure) it is because you include the jsf api but not the impl

Comment: @Kukeltje I have. The source shows the literal `<h:outputText />` tag. I do have jsf-impl in my dependencies, but I hadn't noticed the `<optional>true</optional>` tag. Could that be causing the error?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed them up. Would not suspect the optional to be relevant but you could try. And spring boot does already contain the jsf api?

Comment: Spring Boot does not include neither JSF api or the impl. You need both dependencies with the `compile` scope and not optional. Apart from that, `@ManagedBean` does not work with Spring Boot (I couldn't have it work myself, at least). Here you've what I did to configure it with Spring Boot 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46190826/1199132

Answer (score 1):

Outined here
https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot

You seem to be missing the step to configure JSF with Spring Boot

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.auth0.samples.bootfaces"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
    }
}
```

I'd also add these listeners to integrate spring context with your managed beans:

```
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: I have looked at that tutorial before, and adding that `@Bean` to my `Application` breaks things more by giving me this error:

```Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Jun 22 20:53:42 BST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
```
I could not find a fix for 'Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897900/java-lang-illegalstateexceptioncould-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-ap